# How to display value in DataGridViewComboBoxColumn from database in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcombobox

I am working on Windows Application.
I have a DataGridView in which I am displaying some data from table.
With the addition I have created 1 ComboBoxColumn in DataGridView like this:

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cmbCol = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
cmbCol.Name = "cmbData";
cmbCol.HeaderText = "Data";
cmbCol.ToolTipText = "Data";
DataTable dt = GetList();
cmbCol.ValueMember = dt.Columns[1].ColumnName;
cmbCol.DisplayMember = dt.Columns[1].ColumnName;
cmbCol.DataSource = dt;
this.dgGridVw.Columns.Add(cmbCol);
```

In this way, when I tried to run my application, I am getting values in the ComboBoxColumn.
But Now I want that when run the application, after loading form, ComboBoxColumn should display specific value which is there in Database table.

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to your `ComboBoxColumn` a column name of datagridview datasource:

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cmbCol = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
//...your code...

cmbCol.DataPropertyName = "ColumnNameOfMainDataTable";
this.dgGridVw.Columns.Add(cmbCol);
```